# Post FormData gets empty "req.files" with Multer - 503 on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, multer, form-data

I have to upload a file from `client --> server1`  and then `server1 --> server2`.

> Note: I know I should not store files in heroku, but actually I don't need
> to store the file, I just need it temporary to make some
> modifications, and then pass it to the second service, that will do
> other modifications. for example, let's think to 2 microservices where one
> resizes, one compresses. just as examples. anyway at this step, I just pass
> the file without modify anything.
> Anyway I tried also with `multer-s3`but it's the same exact issue.

I use `multer` on both Node servers deployed on Heroku.
I successfully receive files on server1. When I send files to server2, heroku rises:

- on `server2`:

```
at=warning code=H28 desc="Client Connection Idle" method=POST 
BadRequestError: request aborted app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.onAborted
```

- on `server1`:

```
code=H12 desc="Request timeout"
```

on `server1`, I receive files in this way

```js
/* ==============================
    UPLOAD MIDDLEWARE
============================== */
const multer  = require('multer');
let multer_storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, `${__dirname}/my_uploads`); // <-- be sure this dir already exists, otherwise create it
  }
});

const form_upload = multer({  storage : multer_storage,
                              cb(null, true); }  });

/* ==============================
API ROUTE
============================== */
app.post('/server1/files', 
                  function(req, res)
 {
            
  form_upload.fields([{ name: 'file1' }, { name: 'file2' }])(req, res, (err, body) => {
   // req.files contains file1 and file2 uploaded
   var file1 = req.files["file1"][0];
   var file2 = req.files["file2"][0];
   ...
}
```

Then, alway on `server1`, I send these files to `server2` in this way

```js
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs'); 

const form = new FormData();
form.append("file1", fs.createReadStream(file1.path), file1.originalname);
form.append("file2", fs.createReadStream(file2.path,  file2.originalname);         

var headers = form.getHeaders();    
var config  = { headers:headers };     
axios.post(URL_SERVER2_UPLOAD_API, form, config)
 .then(function(response) { ... });
```

on `server2`, I gets file as in `server1`, with the same multer middleware.
In localhost everything works, I can transfer files between 2 servers. On Heroku, I get those errors. The two files are pretty small (150kb each).

**==== UPDATE 1**

trying directly `client --> server2` and it fails as well. This time I don't get "time out" error, but server just find no files in `req.files`, it's empty.
I don't get it since it's the Same exact server configuration, just on another heroku dyno.
Same thing with `multer-s3`: it works on localhost, not on heroku.
This is server express configuration:

```js
/** ======= server.js ======= */
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();               
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

var server = app.listen(port, function() {...});

app.use('/my_route', require("my_route.js"));
```

```js
/** ======= my_route.js ======= */

var routes = express.Router(); 

function setupCORS(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization,Content-type,Accept'); 
  
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.status(200).end();
  } else {
      next();
  }
}

routes.all('/*', setupCORS);

/* ==============================
    UPLOAD MIDDLEWARE. 
============================== */
const multer  = require('multer');
let multer_storage = multer.diskStorage({..});
const form_upload = multer({..});

// API /my_route/upload
routes.post('/upload', form_upload.any(), function(req, res)
{
 // req.files it's empty here!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start by answering a different question, one that [has lots of answers already](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+uploads+lost), but I think your use case is different enough to warrant one.

### Local storage of uploads is an antipattern

Storing uploads on the local filesystem is an antipattern on Heroku¹: it won't work as expected for the majority of use cases. Dynos have an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), meaning any changes made to them get lost on every restart, which happens frequently and unpredictably ([at least once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts)).

Unless you're just looking for temporary storage, you're going to want another solution. Heroku [recommends](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) using something like Amazon S3 or Azure Blob Storage to store uploads.

The two benefits we usually talk about are that uploads survive dyno restarts and that horizontal scaling becomes much easier—you can spin up a bunch more dynos and they automatically see the uploaded files. You can also dispose of dynos without worrying about losing data.

### Sharing files across services

But in your use case, there's another benefit: your two services can both access the same storage container, which eliminates the need to copy files at all. This is a cleaner solution, and if you want to store uploads for any length of time it's required on Heroku.

---

¹I'd argue it's an antipattern elsewhere, too, for [the same](https://12factor.net/backing-services) [reasons as](https://12factor.net/processes) [on Heroku](https://12factor.net/disposability).

Comment: hi, thank you. actually I don't need to store the file, I just need it temporary to make some modifications, and then pass it to the second service, that will do other modifications. for example, let's think to the micro services 1 resize, 1 compress. just as examples. anyway at this step, I just pass the file without modify anything

Comment: @DeLac, I still think using something like S3 or Blob Storage is the best approach because it eliminates the need to copy anything. It will also scale much better if you need to add a third, fourth, etc. service in the future. The last three links (the ones that go to 12factor.net) might be worth reading. They're short.

Comment: the issue is not about the missing file on the disk storage, in that case I will receive a "file not found" error. In this case req.files it's totally empty. neither the body text it's received. All of this on server2, while on server1 it works great. same node version, dyno version, etc..

Comment: Ah, I see your edit. Missed that while I was writing. The last two snippets are code from `server2`?

Comment: yes it is. but actually it's the same also on server1

Comment: I am trying to use `multer-s3` to store files on AWS, same issue. on localhost it works, on heroku, `req.files` it's empty, I am checking it both inside and outside the upload function

Comment: @DeLac, can you share the client code that tries to submit the files?

Comment: I am using PostMan, form-data body, no custom headers. it's driving me crazy. I just switch to endpoint localhost, server1 and server2 url

Comment: other strange thing, if `req.files` it's empty on server I send `res.status(401).json({ msg :"missing files"});`, but from PostMan I get `503 Service Unavailable`. This only if form-data contains some files. Otherwise 401 json error it's showed. No exception rises from server, since I have a `console.log(error)` right before `res.json`, and it's correct.

Comment: on heroku log, I also see `401` status of the response `POST my_route/upload 401 1.162 ms - 81`. Instead, on PostMan I get 503 as response, with the html page "Application Error".. If no files are passed in the form, I see the correct json error. It makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I solved using `multer-s3` on `server1`, that is able to receive req.files. Then I pass just the link to `server-2`, that will download the files from S3.
Even if this is probably a better solution (as @Chris said), I am forced to use `server1` as first service to use, because it’s the only that receives file correctly. I still don’t know why `service2` receives always an empty `req.files`